# Populating a div with the ajax return of a jsp

Tags: java, ajax, forms, jsp

I currently have 4 forms that are working but not in the best way. They submit to the same page they are on and an if statement intercepts the request.getParameter.

I've looked at prototype.js jQuery, Struts and many others but can't seem to wrap my head around which one to use or which direction to go.

What I mainly want to do is to have a div populate with the data from a jsp.

So the psuedo-code would be something like

- grab the form button submit action
- get the data that /sessioninfo.jsp?sid=data would return
- populate a div with that data.

Is that possible to do or is there a better way?

Example of one of my forms:

```
<form id="sesslook" method="post" action="/MonKaiWeb/index.jsp#tabs-1" name="Session Lookup">
                        <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <h1>User Activity Lookup By NetID</h1>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <input cols="25" type="text" rows="1" name="netid" placeholder="NetID" required/>
                                        <button value="Search" name="Search">Search</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <label for="from">From</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="First Date Exclusive" required />
                                        <label for="to">to</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Last Date Exclusive" required />

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <select id="choice" name="choice" required>
                                            <option value="all">Please Select An Option</option>
                                            <option value="all">Everything</option>
                                            <option value="assnSub">Assignment Submissions</option>
                                            <option value="samSub">Test & Quiz Submission</option>
                                            <option value="db">Upload to DropBox</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Comment: That is possible. Give your `div` an id. When the ajax call returns and has data, select the `div` element by its id and change its `html` content.

Comment: Got it! I was just setting the .html data wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider deleting this question if everything is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Below given  is a very general way to populate the div with ajax response:
Try this:

```
$.post(url, {parameters}, function(response) { div.innerHTML = response });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to populate the div:

```
function doSomething() {
                // get the form values
                va = $('#name').val();
                $.get('newjsp.jsp?ok='+va, function(data) {
                    $('#info').html(data);
                });
            }
```